# Highstock - flag text appears on top of the tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highstock.JS to display a chart. But the text label on flags appear on top of the tooltip. (Picture attached).

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have set `useHTML` for dataLabels for flags - disable it and will work. `useHTML` create html tags, which are always above SVG elements (like tooltip background).