# Highstock - insert HTML link inside flag tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I create a flag data point in the following manner

```
eventData = []
event = {
  x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
  title : 'A',
  text : "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>"
}

series.push({
  type:"flags",
  data:eventData
});
```

Now I get the text "google" but I can't click on it. What's the best way to achieve this?

Also, if this is possible (I'm pretty sure it's possible, because I swear I've seen it before!) is there also a way to open the link in a new tab window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting in a wrong way `a` tag:

`"<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>"`

vs

`'<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'`

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/PLUpR/show/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Now is it possible to open the link in a new window? I tried adding target="_blank" but doesn't seem like it's picking it up.

Comment: Try to set flag `useHTML: true` - otherwise it is rendered as SVG.

Comment: ok, but I reported this bug earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758912/highstock-flag-text-appears-on-top-of-the-tooltip/18759910?noredirect=1#18759910 - which makes the flag labels appear on top of the flag tooltip... is there another workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but for previous issue has another solution - disable default tooltip options (border, background color etc.) and use formatter to render full-html tooltip using formatter and setting `useHTML` flag for tooltip to true. Then using z-index CSS property you should be able to set tooltip above flags.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, I've tested the jsfiddle above and for some reason it works well from a PC (or Mac) but not on an iPad.